# Dart: What's the actual use of Future.sync()? Rather just run the closure without it?

Tags: flutter, dart

From what I can tell reading up about `Future.sync()`, it simply runs the closure supplied to it. I can't imagine a scenario where this might be useful.

So essentially the following two lines of code does the same thing and would be executed at the same time were the one replaced by the other:

```
Future.sync(() => Print('immediately'));
Print('also immediately');
```

Has anyone ever used a Future.sync() for anything useful? Could you describe the scenario?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: And a more direct link: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#solution-using-futuresync-to-wrap-your-code

Comment: Thank you both. So you're saying all that sync does is catch synchronous errors and pass them onto the .catchError()? I feel like this makes 'sync' quite a misnomer.